# For Each loop looking for logs and matches save it separate location

Tags: powershell

I'm planning collect the logs by monthly on first day of every month on each devices.
Example

1. 192.168.1.100 --> Jan --> log1, log2, log3, Feb --> log1, log2, log3 , Mar --> log1, log2, log3

2.192.168.1.101 --> Jan --> log1, log2, log3, Feb --> log1, log2, log3 , Mar --> log1, log2, log3

3.192.168.1.120 --> Jan --> log1, log2, log3, Feb --> log1, log2, log3 , Mar --> log1, log2, log3

so every month script get the previous month format MMM and check the devices path and collects previous month logs and copies it to different location with device name and log file.

this script I'm trying PowerShell. please guys help me. I need it to complete this in my work place.

Thank you all once again for helping me out.

here is my sample code

```
$Month = Get-Date -UFormat %b
$files = Get-ChildItem –Path "C:\temp\logs\"

foreach ($f in $files) {
    if ($Month -eq "May") {
        Write-Host ("Found")
        Copy-Item "C:\temp\logs\" -Filter *.log -Destination C:\temp\Network_Logs\ -Recurse
    }
    else {
        Write-Host ("Not-Found")
    }
}
```

above code copies all log files in all month but i want only may months for all devices.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjaec.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckvz8.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgBNq.png
```

Comment: You can look into the `NTEventLogFile` class using `Get-WMIObject`. It has a `.BackupEventLog()` method you can use to export the log to a *.evt*. The rest is just powershell logic implementing what you want. Would've recommended the newer `Get-EventLog`, or `Get-CimInstance` cmdlets, but they don't offer that handy backup method.

Comment: I am still not sure whether I understand what you want to do but I guess you want to do something like this: `Copy-Item "C:\temp\logs\$Month" -Filter *.log -Destination C:\temp\Network_Logs\$Month`

Comment: if you read my request in the first post. if you able to understand the logic then able to figure it out. i almost got it only i want to copy to the destination if same month on my condition. script is copying even if apr , feb month also. may be my condition is not correct ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? How are the logs per device stored in folder `C:\Logs`? Just files in there or are they already in subfolders? On what criterium do you select _previous month_ logs (last modified time?) Do you want to make copies or **move** them to the new destination?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you would like to do:

```
$logPath    = 'C:\temp\logs'               # the sourcepath where the logs can be found
$logArchive = 'C:\temp\Network_Logs'       # the destination path
$previousMonth = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)  # get last month

# construct the destination path for the log files
$destination = Join-Path -Path $logArchive -ChildPath ('{0:MMM}' -f $previousMonth)
# create the archive month subdirectory
$null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory -Force

Get-ChildItem -Path $logPath -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Month -eq $previousMonth.Month } |
    # copy the files to the destination. 
    # You can change this to Move-Item if that is what you want to do
    Copy-Item -Destination $destination
```

If you mean to have this done on several machines, make sure the archive path is on a network location that can be reached from the different machines and use `Invoke-Command`:

```
$machines   = '192.168.1.100', '192.168.1.101', '192.168.1.120'  # the array of machine names or IP addresses

# create a scriptblock each machine will run 
$scriptBlock = {
    $logPath    = 'C:\temp\logs'                 # the LOCAL sourcepath where the logs can be found on each computer
    $logArchive = '\\server\share\Network_Logs'  # the centralized network destination path (in UNC format)
    $previousMonth = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)    # get last month
    # one way of getting the machines IPV4 address
    $myIP = @([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($env:COMPUTERNAME).AddressList | 
              Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork'})[0].IPAddressToString

    # construct the destination path for the log files
    # will become something like '\\server\share\Network_Logs\192.168.1.100\Apr'
    $destination = Join-Path -Path $logArchive -ChildPath ('{0}\{1:MMM}' -f $myIP, $previousMonth)
    # create the archive path subdirectory
    $null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory -Force

    Get-ChildItem -Path $logPath -File | 
        Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Month -eq $previousMonth.Month } |
        # copy the files to the destination. 
        # You can change this to Move-Item if that is what you want to do
        Copy-Item -Destination $destination
}

# have all machines copy their logfiles to the archive
# if needed, add parameter '-Credential $cred' to this, where the $cred variable is
# obtained via:
#     $cred = Get-Credential -Message 'Please provide admin credentials'

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machines -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock # -Credential $cred
```

Comment: Please see the picture attached to the post. then you will have good understanding. all folder remains in the same server .just logs are to be collected and copied over to destination.

Comment: @AnandVadivelu Not clear at all.. Please show [1] The path on one of the remote servers where it stores the logs [2] What the destination should look like after moving the log files. Please add this to your question either as images (not just links for us to copy/paste in a browser) or as text (use `cmd --> Tree <path> /A /F`)

Comment: C:\TEMP\LOGS
---->10.26.152.101
      BackupState.txt
   ---->Apr
          BackupState.txt
          ChromeSetup.exe
          pw1203-free-online.exe
  ---->Jan
          Bluetooth_Intel_21.30.0.5_W10x64_A.zip
          VGA Utility_Intel_2.5.0.0_W10x64_A.zip
   ---->Jul
          BackupState.txt
   ---->Mar
          Bluetooth_Intel_21.30.0.5_W10x64_A.zip
          VGA Utility_Intel_2.5.0.0_W10x64_A.zip
   ---->May
           101.log
           Audio Console_Realtek_1.2.175.0_W10x64_A.zip
           Audio Utility_Realtek_1.3.181.0_W10x64_A.zip
           BackupState.txt

Comment: my folder structure would be like this as stated above for each device.